# Not able to remove # from url

Tags: angularjs

I tried removing # from the URL like http://locohost:8080/app/#/home .

Tried using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false,
  hasPrefix: ''
});
```

Also added  `<base href=""/> in index.html` inside `<head>` tag

But on hitting the URL  http://locohost:8080/app/home, getting 404 error

Comment: Have you checked this article https://medium.com/@sagar.mane006/removing-from-url-in-angularjs-789f9f0b24a7

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
str.replace("/#/","/")
```

Comment: No the above solution is not working